# I need to validate email is unique, when user enters his email during registration.This should happen on tab function in Angular Js

Tags: html, angularjs, email

On tab functionality control should go to server and check for unique email id and return success or fail mentioned in the errorMessage.

I have written below code and tried using ng-change,ng-blur but control is not hitting.

**Controller.js**

```
checkUniqueEmail(emailId);
function checkUniqueEmail(emailId) {
    MerchantRepository.checkUniqueEmail(emailId)
    .then(function (response){
       scope.errorMessage=response.data;
    },
    function(errResponse){
       console.error('Error while fetching Produce Info:Merchant Side');
    }
    );
};
```

**Repository.js**

```
this.checkUniqueEmail = function(emailId){

   var defer = $q.defer(); 
   //defer is units of work,promise is data from those defer
   var merchantEmailPromise =  http.post('/ABCD1.3/checkMerchantEmail/',emailId);

   merchantEmailPromise.then(function(response){ 
      errorMessage =response;
      defer.resolve(errorMessage);
   });
   return defer.promise;
};
```

**Reg.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
    <input type="email" style="width: 250px; height:40px;" class="form-control"
    name="emailId" 
    ng-model="merchant.emailId" placeholder="Enter  Email Id"
    ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="50"
    ng-change="checkUniqueEmail(emailId)" />
    {{errorMessage}}
</div>
```

Can anyone help with this,
tried lot more times and left out blank.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue and posting the same if incase anyone needs

**Reg.html**

`<input type="email" name="emailId" ng-model="user.emailId" x-ng-blur="checkUniqueEmail(merchant.emailId)" required />`

**UserController.js**

```
scope.checkUniqueEmail = function(email) {
    Repository.checkUniqueEmail(email)
        .then(function(response) {
            var mEmail = response.data.status;
                if (mEmail != null) {
                    scope.errorMessage2 = mEmail;
                    } else {
                    scope.errorMessage2 = "";
                }
            });
        };
```

**Repository.js**

```
this.checkUniqueEmail = function(email){

var defer = $q.defer(); 
var EmailPromise = http.post('/ProjectName/checkMerchantEmail/',email);
EmailPromise.then(function(response){ 
    errorMessage =response;
    defer.resolve(errorMessage);
});
return defer.promise;
```

};

From here your server side implementation to check from database.

Answer (score 0):

as i seen in the query, there is only "response" promise, so always give to controller response OK, not KO.

```
this.checkUniqueEmail = function(emailId){

   var defer = $q.defer(); 
   //defer is units of work,promise is data from those defer
   var merchantEmailPromise =  http.post('/ABCD1.3/checkMerchantEmail/',emailId);

   merchantEmailPromise.then(function(response){ 
   errorMessage =response;
   **defer.resolve(errorMessage);**
});
   return defer.promise;
};
```

And there is some, i cant understad why being a Ok response, the param is called errorMessage.
AT last you must create a "defer.reject(errorMessage);" when is KO, and tell us.

Comment: whith out from promise, will be an enought event, to capture when is done, not?

Comment: then you can put this tab in ng-if, and put too ng-init. This s like your on-tab event. Will dispatch ng-init whe ng-if is true

Comment: <div tab-that-you-make-event ng-if="visible" ng-init="eventotodispacth()"></div>

Comment: add the ng-init, ng-if to parent dom